# Asp.net gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a text box inside gridview. I need to get the id of textbox in javascript. When i use like this  '<%= txtNewQty.ClientID %>'; it  gives the compilation error.

Comment: onwhich event you want to get textbox in javascript

Comment: do any of the answers here answer your question? Or do you need more information?

Comment: Nothing helps me out. iam not able to get the client id of the textbox control which is added as an itemtemplate in the gridview.

Comment: Does my new answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtNewQty` does not exist at the page level and therefore you will not be able to reference it in that manner. you'll have to do something like generate the js on the server side or work your way down from the gridview element. post some code and a description of what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Controls inside Gridviews are not members of the Page, they just exist in the .aspx . They are gonna be repeated in each row so they are dinamically created.

To get a reference of the Control inside a row of the Gridview you can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
{
    Textbox tb = row.FindControl("txtNewQtv") as Textbox;
    string id = tb.ClientID;
    //Generate your javascript here so it can be callable on the client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bad way to do it as it is hardcoded to the column index. It works but there must be a better way using jQuery. Unfortunately I'm not an expert with that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Update(btn) {
        alert(btn.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].children[0].id);
    }
</script>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewQtv" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="button" onclick="Update(this)" value="Update" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```